# Is there an equivalent of waitForAngular() when using Java-based selenium?

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, protractor

We are using the Java-based API for Selenium to test our Angular 1.3 app. For various reasons, we cannot use Protractor. However, there is some functionality that we need to test where an `ExplicitWait` like `waitForAngular()` would work. In particular, we need to know when all $http requests are completed and the digest cycle is finished.

However, this is not available in vanilla Selenium.  Is there an alternative that we can try?

I'm thinking that the answer would be something like calling `syncExec` with a script that would run on the browser and run some angular magic to check this. Any ideas?

Comment: waitfor `$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){ ... }` trigger?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue and came across this: https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver from Paul Hammant.

It seems to be offering a good set of functionality, although I confess I've not had time to get it going yet. But seeing as this post is a few months old without reply I thought I'd give it a mention.

Answer (score 1):

Does this works for you: driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(time, unit). If not you can try JavascriptExecutor to execute javascript specific code to wait for page to load.